# Very strange tensorflow behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dependencies, control-flow

I have very simple lines that produce very strange unexpected behavior:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)

a1 = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
a2 = tf.assign(y, y * 2)

with tf.control_dependencies([a1, a2]):
    t = y+0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(4):
        print('t=%d' % sess.run(t))
        print('y=%d' % sess.run(y))
```

What is expected is

```
t=6
y=6
t=14
y=14
t=30
y=30
t=62
y=62
```

But first run, I got:

```
t=6
y=6
t=13
y=13
t=26
y=26
t=27
y=27
```

Second run, I got:

```
t=3
y=3
t=6
y=6
t=14
y=14
t=15
y=15
```

Third run, I got:

```
t=6
y=6
t=14
y=14
t=28
y=28
t=56
y=56
```

Very ridiculous, multiple runs produces multiple different output sequences, very strange, can someone help?

EDIT: changing to

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)

a1 = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
a2 = tf.assign(y, y * 2)
a3 = tf.group(a1, a2)
with tf.control_dependencies([a3]):
    t = tf.identity(y+0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(4):

        print('t=%d' % sess.run(t))
        print('y=%d' % sess.run(y))
```

...still doesn't work properly.

It is still strange that this code:

```
a1 = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
with tf.control_dependencies([a1]):
  a2 = tf.assign(y, y * 2)
  with tf.control_dependencies([a2]):
    t = tf.identity(y)
```

... works properly, but simply move `a2` to before as

```
a1 = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
a2 = tf.assign(y, y * 2)
with tf.control_dependencies([a1]):
  with tf.control_dependencies([a2]):
    t = tf.identity(y)
```

... it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the order of `a1` and `a2` matters too: you want `a1` to be evaluated before `a2`. `tf.control_dependencies([a1, a2])` guarantees that `t` is performed after both `a1` and `a2`, but they themselves can be evaluated in any order.

I'd go with explicit dependency like that:

```py
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
a1 = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
with tf.control_dependencies([a1]):
  a2 = tf.assign(y, y * 2)
  with tf.control_dependencies([a2]):
    t = tf.identity(y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(4):
    print('t=%d' % sess.run(t))
    print('y=%d' % sess.run(y))
```

Output:

```py
t=6
y=6
t=14
y=14
t=30
y=30
t=62
y=62
```

Comment: could you pls see my update, I found another strange problem

Comment: Correct. Check the semantics of `control_dependency`: the dependent op should be defined inside the context, not before